# .Net 6 - exception middleware not catching authorization error

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, middleware

Thanks in advanced.
I am trying to create custom exception middleware to catch all error to be in same file and same format.
As far as I am throwing an Exception it works fine I catch the error and it goes trough my custom exception middleware.
When its coming to authorization exception its not going trough my custom exception handler and I cant find the reason.
I was trying to reorder the start up file and putting the middleware first and still not working.
I was trying to remove developer exception and still not working.

I think its something I am missing but I cant point on it.

Appreciate your help

my start up file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration configRoot
    {
        get;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddScoped<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
        // Add services to the container.
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddSingleton<ITokenService>(new TokenService());
        services.AddSingleton<IUserService>(new UserService());
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<CampaignService>();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = new()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidIssuer = configRoot["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = configRoot["Jwt:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configRoot["Jwt:Key"]))
            };
        });

        services.AddDbContext<PlatformContextProcedures>(
        options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(configRoot.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnectionString"),
                Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.23-mysql"));
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                        .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

And also my middleware:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{ 
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, HttpStatusCodeException exception)
    {
        string? result = null;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        if (exception is HttpStatusCodeException)
        {
            result = new ErrorDetails()
            {
                Message = exception.Message,
                StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode
            }.ToString();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;
        }
        else
        {
            result = new ErrorDetails()
            {
                Message = "Runtime Error",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            }.ToString();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        string result = new ErrorDetails()
        {
            Message = exception.Message,
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        }.ToString();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

So when I am throwing Exception it works

```
throw new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "invalid username or password");
```

but when I do Authorized Attribute its not going to my exception is throwing 401 directly
I registered Authorization globally this way on start up file

```
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

Appreciate you all and thanks in advanced.

Comment: Authentication and authorization happen *before* an action is executed. The authorization middleware doesn't throw, it returns a 401 immediately, as it should.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to change the 401 response with a custom response and what do you want to return? There may be a way to do this properly. You could create your own Authorization filter and return a custom response if authorization fails.

Comment: I am trying to make a consist Error response and handling all errors at the same file

Comment: That's not an error so it doesn't need an error response. It doesn't raise any exceptions to catch. A meaningful response would be to redirect to a login page, or return an empty response with just a 401 status

Comment: So basically I need to create and authorization filter and handle authorization issues from that filter? if i want to achieve consist error response to the client?

Comment: There's no error. Unless you accept that, you won't find any solution. You won't understand why *clients* will complain that your service is unusable because it returns unexpected, non-standard responses. What response do you want to send and why isn't a 401 with an empty body enough? In an API, that's all that's needed, unless you want to add information like `token expired`. In a web app, redirecting to login, or a custom access request page may be better.

Comment: If you check [the middleware order in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order), exception filtering happens *after* an action runs, which is the only point where user exceptions are expected. That's long after the authorization step.

Comment: If you check the possible duplicate you'll see how the Unauthorized response can be customized in meaningful ways, eg telling the client they need to refresh their JWT and retry

Comment: I get that's not an error, and I get your point. so its good behavior that its not going trough my middleware since its not error. I just wanted to make sure I am not missing anything. thanks for your explanation. appreciate.

Comment: You need to consider another thing though - if authorization happens late, or depends on exceptions, it would be very easy to launch a DDoS attack against a site using unauthorized requests. The sooner one can discard bad requests, the better.